# How do i have a cron run and check which crons are currently running

Tags: ubuntu, cron, shell

I have an ubuntu server that i have some scripts that need to run on a cron. The first is a shells script and the second is a php script. How do I check to see what is running currently on cron and how do I add these two files to run on cron daily or hourly. Not sure what the client needs yet. Is there a file i need to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab -l` displays the scheduled jobs for current user.

You can edit the cron jobs with this command `crontab -e`.

Each line represents:

```
<minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <command to be executed>
```

e.g. the following line execute a script every 30 minutes (0 and 30 on the clock).

```
0,30  *   *   *   *   /home/user1/script.sh
```

Take a look at [this reference](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) for more detail.